# Open cover, finite subcover

Tags: real-analysis

> Find an open cover of $(-\infty,0]$ that does not have a finite subcover.

Can anyone help me with this? Please explain the intuition of finding it too.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you give a non-trivial example of an open cover for that set?

Comment: Try a sequence of nested open intervals [each of finite length] whose union is $(-\infty,0]$.

Comment: Just don't make the intervals too big. Try to understand what I mean by that and how it applies to the problem.

Comment: Can you do the same to $\mathbb R$? The canonical example there works without major modification here.

Comment: Hint: There are much simpler answers to the problem than the solutions offered so far, so try to find your own solution.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales: What is more simpler than forming your cover by taking a ball of any fixed radius about every point in the interval. The finite sub cover would then imply that the interval contains finitely many points, which is not true and so the problem is done.

Comment: @UnusualSkill Select your intervals so that you know each number in $(-\infty,0]$ is contained in at least one interval, but restrict the size of your intervals so that no finite number of them could possibly cover the entire set  $(-\infty,0]$. Now I have practically told you the answer.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood You just said it much more simply than originally, except that a ball is a closed set. One only needs open intervals of a fixed radius about each point of the set. It does not take any mathematical notation to say this.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales the notation which is commonly used for closed ball is $\bar{B}(1,r)$ and for open its just $B(1,r)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very easy solution is just $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(-n,0].$$ Clearly it can't be finite, and it's open.

If the space isn't to be taken as $(-\infty,0]$, then take the union to be $$\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty(-n,1).$$

Comment: Hm governor, I thought open cover meant each covering element $V_n$ in the cover $C = \{V_n\}$ i.e. $(-n, 0]$ should be open?

Comment: @SarahPalinsAnger: They are open. In the subspace topology that $(-\infty, 0]$ inherits as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you take the space as $(-\infty,0]$, they are open.

Comment: @Clayton: I didn't mean to intrude. This is a nice answer. The OP would have to know some general topology though.

Comment: @Faraad: I suppose it depends what part of the course they are in. At any rate, I'll add an edit to include up to $1$.

Comment: @Clayton Sorry I misunderestimated the topology involved

Answer (score 0):

For every rational number $r \in A = (-\infty, 0]$ take $\{B(1,r)\}_{r \in A}$. Given any $x \in A$, we know by density of rationals that there exists $r_x$ such that $|r_x - x|< \epsilon<1 \Rightarrow x \in B(1,r_x)$. However, if we suppose $\{B(1,r_i)\}_{i =1}^n$ is a finite sub cover. Then if we take $s < \min\{r_i\} - 2$, so $s \in A \setminus \bigcup_i B(1,r_i)$.

Answer (score 0):

One way of going about this is to find an open cover where, if any sets are missing, it clearly dons't cover the set.

For example, consider $\{(k-3/4,k+3/4):k\in\Bbb{Z}\}$. In other words, we put a cover around each integer with length $1.5$ (to make sure they overlap). If any of these sets $(k-3/4,k+3/4)$ is missing, then $k$ is not covered. Thus we always will need each $k\in\Bbb{Z}$ where $k\le 0$.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two ways to do this.

(1) infinitely many intervals but a finite number of centers.

For example, all intervals with finite radius and center 0.

(2) infinitely many intervals but with bounded radii.

For example, all intervals with center in $(-\infty,0]$ and radius 1.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you want $C = \{(-n-2, -n+2), n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

Let $V_n = (-n-2, -n+2)$

Then $[0, \infty) \subseteq \bigcup\limits_{n = 1}^\infty V_n $

Try to find an finite subcover $U$ such that $[0, \infty)  \subseteq U$, you can't!

Comment: I believe Apurv wants an open cover.

Comment: @Bungo Oh honey just reverse em!

Comment: You betcha!$\ \ \ \ $

Comment: @Bungo Drill baby drill...on those problem sets